# Oracle - materialized view or table

Tags: oracle

I have a table (in Oracle 12c) with 22 million records so far, and plus 10,000 records inserted every day. We need the counts based on this table, such as:

```
select col1, col2, count(*) cnt from my_table group by col1, col2;
```

This query will return less than 30 rows, and the combination of `col1`, `col2` will be unique.

Our application needs to check the `CNT` value frequently, but the approximate values of the `CNT` are good enough. That means we can create a materialized view and refresh it every 10-20 Minutes.

Is the materialized view a good choice for this requirement, or should I create a regular table for it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: MView itself creates a table with the data returned from the view. So I don't see the difference

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590, true, a MV is just a table based on a view. But, with one simple create statement it creates the table, the view, the scheduled job to populate and refresh the table; in short it's like one stop shopping. In the right circumstances, MV's are very handy.

Comment: Maybe create BITMAP INDEX on `col1` and `col2` (one on each column). Then the query should be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three different ways to achieve this:

1. **Fast Refresh Materialized View**  A fast refresh materialized view is probably the ideal solution.  The 10,000 rows inserted will have a small amount of overhead but then there is no need to rebuild anything; the new totals are available immediately after each commit and retrieving the new totals will be incredibly fast.  The downside is that fast refresh materialized views are difficult to setup, and have lots of weird gotchas.  They work well with your sample schema but may not work with a more complicated scenario.

   *Sample Schema*

   ```
   drop table my_table;

   create table my_table(
       id number not null,
       col1 number not null,
       col2 number not null,
       constraint my_table_pk primary key (id)
   );

   insert into my_table
   select level, mod(level, 30), mod(level+1, 30)
   from dual
   connect by level <= 100000;

   begin
       dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MY_TABLE');
   end;
   /
   ```

   *Create materialized view log and materialized view*

   ```
   create materialized view log on my_table with rowid(col1, col2) including new values;

   create materialized view my_table_mv
   refresh fast on commit
   enable query rewrite as
   select col1, col2, count(*) total
   from my_table
   group by col1, col2;
   ```

   *Query rewrite*

   The sample query is silently modified to use the small materialized view instead of the large table.

   ```
   explain plan for
   select col1, col2, count(*) cnt
   from my_table
   group by col1, col2;

   select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

   Plan hash value: 786752524

   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Id  | Operation                    | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |             |    30 |   300 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |   1 |  MAT_VIEW REWRITE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE_MV |    30 |   300 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```
2. **Compressed B*Tree Index**  If there are only 30 unique values the index should compress well and not take up much space.  Then the index can be used in
   a fast full index scan and act like a skinny table.  This method requires at least one value to be not null.  If both could be null then a function-based
   index could be useful here.

   ```
   create index my_table_idx on my_table(col1, col2) compress;
   ```
3. **Bitmap index** Bitmap indexes are small and fast when there are a small number of distinct values.  However they can introduce disastrous locking problems
   for some types of DML.

   ```
   create bitmap index my_table_idx on my_table(col1, col2);
   ```

Comment: If the rows are inserted into the table using the direct path method /*+ APPEND */ then you can drop the use of the materialized view log, by the way.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I'll edit to make it clearer that I'm discussing three unrelated methods.  The materialized view log is necessary for the materialized view.  That way adding 10,000 records doesn't require rebuilding the whole table.

Comment: no I think the answer is clear enough. I'm just saying (mostly for future readers) that refresh fast on commit does not need an MV log if the only changes to the table are inserts via Direct Path -- they would not be represented in the MV log, and Oracle uses a different mechanism for fast refresh on commit for direct path inserts.

Comment: I'm racking my brain for the name of the system table that is used for direct path fast refresh in lieu of the MV log, but it escapes me.

Comment: here you go -- I knew I'd written something up about this. https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2005/11/23/optimizing-materialized-views-part-iii-manual-refresh-mechanisms/

Comment: @DavidAldridge That's an interesting article.  But to it does imply that a materialized view log is necessary even though it isn't used.  And I can't get an example to work without one.

Comment: there could be version-dependent issues (deliberate and/or bugs) with this, as fast refresh has changed a lot over the years -- 12c will allow refresh based on data not yet loaded to a table, for example. You might like to look into using DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW to see what the optimiser states can be done in the absence of an MV Log.

Comment: @JonHeller Thank you very much for your suggestions. I use MView without the log to get the counts, and the MView gets refreshed very 20 minutes. It works with pretty good performance as we expected.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how approximate your method can be, you can also try a SAMPLE clause:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       count(*) cnt
from   my_table sample(1)
group by col1, col2;
```

Depending on the data distribution of the values this might give a reasonable estimate. You can test how high a number you need in order to give a reasonable result, but it's rarely worth going over 4 or 5 unless using the block clause:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       count(*) cnt
from   my_table sample block(10)
group by col1, col2;
```